Zephyr - C - Deep copy of struct produce unexpected result
Some context
I'm currently working with Bluetooth Low Energy on an embedded system using Zephyr.
During the services/characteristics/CCCDs discovering (my embedded device is the BLE central), I want to store every characteristics so I can use them later (mainly read them).
For that I'm using the linked list provide by Zephyr and I allocate my node using k_calloc().
typedef struct lst_chrc_node_s {
  sys_snode_t     node;
  struct bt_uuid  *uuid;
  uint16_t        value_handle;
  uint8_t         properties;
  uint8_t         type;
} lst_chrc_node_t;

lst_chrc_node_t *list_create_node(struct bt_gatt_chrc *chrc, uint8_t type)
{
  lst_chrc_node_t *new_node = k_calloc(1, sizeof(new_node));
  if (!new_node)
    return NULL;
  
  new_node->uuid = k_calloc(1, sizeof(new_node->uuid));
  if (!new_node->uuid)
  {
    k_free(new_node);
    return NULL;
  }
  
  print_uuid128("UUID that will be store", chrc->uuid);
  *new_node->uuid = *chrc->uuid;
  new_node->value_handle = chrc->value_handle;
  new_node->properties = chrc->properties;
  new_node->type = type;
  print_uuid128("UUID that was stored   ", new_node->uuid);

  return new_node;
}

As you can see, I want to store the struct bt_gatt_chrc *chrc that is passed in the function's arguments. However, this structure contains a constant pointer to an other struct named bt_uuid. This bt_uuid struct is important because I will need it to read the correct characteristic from the BLE peripheral.
My linked list's node doesn't have directly the bt_gatt_chrc struct but has the same member one by one. This because I can't directly copy the bt_gatt_chrc from argument to linked list's node because the const pointer to bt_uuid has the same address when discovering services, characteristics and CCCDs (It change when discovering a different GATT Attribute's type but will still the same for this type of attribute).
The problem
After creating the node and copying data in it, the bt_uuid value isn't the same as the one I received from the BLE peripheral.
Here is the log for one standard UUID:
[00:00:04.293,914] <inf> main: UUID received           UUID 128: 070002a4-5720-0045-2020-0013072a0000
[00:00:04.293,945] <inf> main: UUID that will be store UUID 128: 070002a4-5720-0045-2020-0013072a0000
[00:00:04.293,975] <inf> main: UUID that was stored    UUID 128: 00000d00-0d61-8c00-0200-020003000000

I feel pretty stupid because AFAIU, my issue seems clearly to be in this line *new_node->uuid = *chrc->uuid; but I don't see what I'm doing wrong. I tried to cast the const struct bt_uuid to just struct bt_uuid, the result wasn't good either (it looks like even more wrong as the entire 128-bit UUID changes between each standard characteristics (defined by the Bluetooth SIG) instead of staying pretty close to the same (like just 2-3 digits change between characteristics without casting the struct).
Is it because the bt_uuid is a "tentative" type and so I can't use it this way ? Can someone rephrase what is a tentative type ? I'm clearly not sure about my understanding of this.

I have no idea what is a tentative type, but it looks like https://docs.zephyrproject.org/apidoc/latest/uuid_8h_source.html the storage for uuid depends on the type, and the space is allocated dynamically. This is one of the cheap ways to implement inheritance in C.

Rather than a "tentative" type, I think you meant an "incomplete" type. But if the type was incomplete, you wouldn't be able to use sizeof or = on it.

k_calloc(1, sizeof(new_node)) looks extremely suspicious. Shouldn't it be sizeof *new_node instead? Same with new_node->uuid = k_calloc(1, sizeof(new_node->uuid));.

@IanAbbott I was saying "tentative" because it's what the Zephyr's documentation says

@KamilCuk Oh, I didn't knew about this inheritance implementation in C, it's quite interesting

From uuid.h:
enum {
        BT_UUID_TYPE_16,
        BT_UUID_TYPE_32,
        BT_UUID_TYPE_128,
};
 
#define BT_UUID_SIZE_16                  2
 
#define BT_UUID_SIZE_32                  4
 
#define BT_UUID_SIZE_128                 16
 
struct bt_uuid {
        uint8_t type;
};
 
struct bt_uuid_16 {
        struct bt_uuid uuid;
        uint16_t val;
};
 
struct bt_uuid_32 {
        struct bt_uuid uuid;
        uint32_t val;
};
 
struct bt_uuid_128 {
        struct bt_uuid uuid;
        uint8_t val[BT_UUID_SIZE_128];
};

The struct bt_uuid * should point to enough memory to store a struct bt_uuid_16, a struct bt_uuid_32, or a struct bt_uuid_128, depending on the value of the type member BT_UUID_TYPE_16, BT_UUID_TYPE_32, or BT_UUID_TYPE_128.
EDIT: The line lst_chrc_node_t *new_node = k_calloc(1, sizeof(new_node)); in OP's original code is wrong (spotted by @chux in the comment below, and @ach in the comment on the question), and has been corrected in the code below.
Untested, modified code:
lst_chrc_node_t *list_create_node(struct bt_gatt_chrc *chrc, uint8_t type)
{
  lst_chrc_node_t *new_node;
  size_t bt_uuid_size;

  switch (chrc->uuid->type)
  {
  case BT_UUID_TYPE_16:
    bt_uuid_size = sizeof(struct bt_uuid_16);
    break;
  case BT_UUID_TYPE_32:
    bt_uuid_size = sizeof(struct bt_uuid_32);
    break;
  case BT_UUID_TYPE_128:
    bt_uuid_size = sizeof(struct bt_uuid_128);
    break;
  default:
    return NULL;
  }
  new_node = k_calloc(1, sizeof(*new_node));
  if (!new_node)
    return NULL;
  
  new_node->uuid = k_calloc(1, bt_uuid_size);
  if (!new_node->uuid)
  {
    k_free(new_node);
    return NULL;
  }
  
  print_uuid128("UUID that will be store", chrc->uuid);
  memcpy(new_node->uuid, chrc->uuid, bt_uuid_size);
  new_node->value_handle = chrc->value_handle;
  new_node->properties = chrc->properties;
  new_node->type = type;
  print_uuid128("UUID that was stored   ", new_node->uuid);

  return new_node;
}


new_node = k_calloc(1, sizeof(new_node)); looks wrong.  Did you want new_node = k_calloc(1, sizeof(new_node[0])); ?
